# Within a Linked List in Ruby, the method add_at with index is not working right

Tags: ruby

I am studying Ruby, and this Linked list exercise is a little complicated for me, I advanced, but not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :next_node
  alias_method :next, :next_node

  def initialize(value, next_node = nil)
    @value = value
    @next_node = next_node
  end

  def next
    @next_node
  end
end

class LinkedList
  attr_accessor :head, :tail

  def initialize
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end

  def add(number)
    if @head.nil?
      new_node = Node.new(number)
      @head = new_node
      @tail = new_node
    else
      new_node = Node.new(number)
      @tail.next_node = new_node
      @tail = new_node
    end
  end

  def get(index)
    current = @head
    index.times do
      current = current.next_node
    end
    return current.value
  end

  def add_at(index, item)
    current = head
    (index - 1).times do
      raise "List not long enough" if current.nil?
      current = current.next_node
    end

    new_node = Node.new(item)    
    new_node.next_node = current.next_node   
    current.next_node = new_node  
  end
end
```

Tried to change the Node method, but seems like that is not the answer

Everything seems fine to me, but the data is not sorted in the right position according the following test:

```
list = LinkedList.new

list.add(3)
list.add(5)
list.add_at(1, 11)
list.add_at(0, 13)

puts list.get(#)
```

should be 13,3,11,5 at the end

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LinkedList#add_at` method does not work correctly when inserting to the beginning (or end) of the list.

In particular, when calling `list.add_at(0, 13)`, where's what happens:

```
def add_at(index, item)
  current = head # Current is set to the "3" node
  (index - 1).times do # This never yields
    raise "List not long enough" if current.nil?
    current = current.next_node
  end

  new_node = Node.new(item) # Creates the "13" node
  new_node.next_node = current.next_node # "13" points to "11"
  current.next_node = new_node # "3" points to "13"
end
```

Result: Instead of turning `3 --> 11 --> 5` into `13 --> 3 --> 11 --> 5`, you've turned it into `3 --> 13 --> 11 --> 5`.

In other words, the end result of calling `list.add_at(0, 13)` is the same as calling `list.add_at(1, 13)`.

I don't want to dictate a single solution to you here; the key takeaway should be **how to debug the problem**. For example, you could try installing [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry), add `binding.pry` into the method and step through the code to reproduce my summary.
This is an absolutely vital developer skill that's needed to solve problems of this manner.

...But with that said, here's a suggestion: Re-use the existing methods to fetch the `previous` and `next` nodes; then re-set the `head`/`tail` values if necessary (as well as "inserting" the new node into the list):

```
def add_at(index, item)
  new_node = Node.new(item)

  previous_node = get(index-1)
  next_node = get(index)

  if previous_node
    previous_node.next_node = new_node
  else
    head = new_node
  end

  if next_node
    new_node.next_node = next_node
  else
    tail = new_node
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution doesn't run to be honestly hehe, but the idea of using a previous_node seems very helpful

Comment: @FeberCastellon It probably doesn't work because your `get` method also returns the wrong thing with an index of `-1` (the above assumes it will return `nil`, but your version will return `@head`). .... But as I said, this is only meant to be an idea to point you in the right direction rather than an attempt to completely rewrite the whole thing :)